# How to count matches in tokoneized dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, which contains 599 tokenized texts, one per row. Also i have these lists:

```
grwoth = ['growth', 'grow', 'growing', 'grows']
syergies = ['synergies', 'synergy' ,'accretive', 'accretion','efficiencies' ,'efficient', 'efficiently' ]
intangibles = ['brand','branded','branding','brands','goodwill','patent','patents','goodwil']
customers = ['customer', 'customers' ,'consumer' ,'consumers' ]
technology = ['technological', 'technologically', 'technologies', 'technology', 'innovate', 'innovation', 'innovations', 'innovative', 'innovator', 'innovators']
human = ['employee', 'employees', 'employees', 'team', 'teamed', 'teaming', 'teams', 'Expertise' ]
```

I want to create a new column in my dataframe for each list and to count how often the words from the lists has been counted in each text.

I tried to input them into my orginal dataframe (without tokenization) but this didnt work either. I Had the following code:

```
%%time

    growth = ['growth', 'grow', 'growing', 'grows']
    synergies = ['synergies', 'synergy' ,'accretive', 'accretion','efficiencies' ,'efficient', 'efficiently' ]
    intangibles = ['brand','branded','branding','brands','goodwill','patent','patents','goodwil']
    customers = ['customer', 'customers' ,'consumer' ,'consumers' ]
    technology = ['technological', 'technologically', 'technologies', 'technology', 'innovate', 'innovation', 'innovations', 'innovative', 'innovator', 'innovators']
    human = ['employee', 'employees', 'employees', 'team', 'teamed', 'teaming', 'teams', 'expertise' ]
    the = 'Wire'

    result_list=[]
    count_growth = 0
    count_human = 0
    count_technology= 0
    count_customers = 0
count_intagibles = 0
count_synergies = 0
count_the = 0
for file in file_list:
    name = file[len(input_path):]
    date = name[11:17]
    type_1 = name[17:20]
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as rfile:
            # We need to encode/decode as some text files are not in utf-8 format
            text = rfile.read()
            text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

    for word in text.split():
        if word in growth:
            count_growth = count_growth +1
        if word in synergies:
            count_synergies = count_synergies +1 
        if word in intagibles:
            count_intagibles = count_intagibles+1
        if word in customers:
            count_customers = count_customers +1
        if word in technology:
            count_technology = count_technology +1
        if word in human:
            count_human = count_human +1
        if word == 'The':
            count_the = count_the +1
    length = len(text.split())




    a={"File": name, "Text": text,'the':count_the, 'Datum': date, 'File_type': type_1, 'length':length, 'grwoth':count_growth, 'synergies': count_synergies,'intagibles':count_intagibles,'customers':count_customers, 'technology':count_technology,'human':count_human,}
    result_list.append(a)
```

The problem here was, that it creates a total sum but not a sum for each row as it does for length.

Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Comment: What do you mean with "it creates a total sum but not a sum for each row as it does for length"?
What would you like to see at the end?

Comment: at the end i would like to see for example in column customers in row 1: 5, row 2: 3 etc. instead it counts how many time there have been in the previous ro and simply adds the count for the next row so if in row1 there are 5 appreancec and in row2 3 the value in row 2 = 8
In addition: It counts the length for each text seperately so e.g. row1:394, row2: 569 but not row2: = 394+569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to clear the variables inside the for loop. This way it outputs the count for the various files, as it does for the length.

I hope I understood correctly what you wanted to do.

Code below:

```
for file in file_list:
    count_growth = 0
    count_human = 0
    count_technology= 0
    count_customers = 0
    count_intagibles = 0
    count_synergies = 0
    count_the = 0
    name = file[len(input_path):]
    date = name[11:17]
    type_1 = name[17:20]
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as rfile:
            # We need to encode/decode as some text files are not in utf-8 format
            text = rfile.read()
            text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

    for word in text.split():
        if word in growth:
            count_growth = count_growth +1
        if word in synergies:
            count_synergies = count_synergies +1 
        if word in intagibles:
            count_intagibles = count_intagibles+1
        if word in customers:
            count_customers = count_customers +1
        if word in technology:
            count_technology = count_technology +1
        if word in human:
            count_human = count_human +1
        if word == 'The':
            count_the = count_the +1
    length = len(text.split())    
    a={"File": name, "Text": text,'the':count_the, 'Datum': date, 'File_type': type_1, 'length':length, 'grwoth':count_growth, 'synergies': count_synergies,'intagibles':count_intagibles,'customers':count_customers, 'technology':count_technology,'human':count_human,}
    result_list.append(a)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it...so clumsy...
But neverthe less how would the approach for the already tokenized text work? if i dont want to intgrate this in my original dataframe?

Comment: I think that should be another question, I am unsure what you are asking and we should not discuss too much in the comment session. Please provide examples of the desired output when asking a question.